# Safari background image strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

**UPD**

Safari (I tested 9.1.2 version) have an interesting behavior: `style.backgroundImage` returns image path including host and protocol:
[image]

Inspecting element confirms this fact:
[image]

`setAttribute` behaviour is also strange: inspect element shows normal path, but `style.backgroundImage` still returns path with host and protocol:
[image]

**Original question**

I have some strange bug and trying to find its roots, so I need your help.

I'm using jQuery `css` method to set background image, some like that:

```
$element.css( 'background-image', 'url(' + path_to_image + ')' );
```

Variable `path_to_image` contains path to image, for example `'/some/dir/image.jpg'`.
 Application is quite big and at some stage I've noticed that background image has changed: host and protocol was added! Background image looks like 'http://domain.com/some/dir/image.jpg' now.
So, my question is there any probabilty that jQuery `css` method could be able to add host and protocol by itself? Did you ever heard about this kind of bug? Any OS or any browser?
Thanks

Comment: path starting with `/` are not relative...

Comment: can you tell us where are you checking for the generated link after page loads?

Comment: @n00dl3 sure, typo

Comment: @mondersky app is really big and it processes generated HTML between backend and frontend many times. After few iterations I've found this bug and now trying to understand is it frontend or backend bug

Answer (score 0):

jquery doesn't add the domain name to your background link when you use the css function, so that happens after it and it's not related to jQuery